# onLocationChange() Listener not being called

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, locationlistener

Before explaining my problem, I ask that you please bear with me. I realize this question has been asked before, but I went through all S.O. posts related to this, and none of them were really able to solve my problem. I will try to be as accurate as possible:

I am simply trying to get my user's location. I have requested the appropriate permissions on the Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And I have made the call to request location in two different ways:

```
//Get Location
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 360,
                    10, mLocationListener);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 360,
                    10, mLocationListener);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then, I instantiate my listener as such:

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("THIS IS NOT BEING CALLED", "GOT LOCATION");
                }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
```

I also tried making that listener into a custom class "MyLocationListener" which I try to instantiate in my onCreate() method on my activity.

Furthermore, I checked that my GPS was on, both by checking settings and by using the Maps app.

None of this has worked for me. Is there anything else that I might be missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is that a `LocationListener` from the `android.location.LocationListener` package or from some external library? Those overridden methods suggest that you have implemented some other `LocationListener` than the correct one. Check your `import` statements.

Comment: import android.location.LocationListener; The other overrides are from the Firebase library.. I cleaned them up.

Comment: mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 360,
                    10, mLocationListener);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 360,
                    10, mLocationListener); are the same why?

Comment: typo.. the second is actually NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: Check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37203191/5392118).

Comment: I think minimum distance parameter should be float, so assign it like 10f. I resolved the same issue by doing so. Hope It may help some one